# Paillier Crypto System : Pros and Cons?

Tags: paillier

Can you please list the pros and cons of the Paillier crypto system you have encountered or found?

Comment: Compared to which other cryptosystems? Your question is a bit broad in its current form, you might want to elaborate a bit.

Comment: Please also make sure to describe what research you've done.  We expect you to show some evidence of effort on your own before asking.  Make sure to read the help center.

Answer (score 1):

Without anything to compare Paillier, the list will be small but here goes:

Pros:

1. Has seen a fair amount of proposed application in the published literature
2. Thanks to #1 there are a number of special constructions (e.g. zero-knowledge proofs) that have been built for Paillier
3. Is additively homomorphic

Cons:

1. Lacks small ciphertexts like what you get with elliptic curve crypto
2. No standards that I'm aware of